# Complex (PHP) regex with positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to match the following test string (**line 2** and **line 3**), where **line 3** would be in random order and **line 2** would be a constant.

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            IP Address:55.66.77.88, DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com, IP Address:44.33.22.11
Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
```

I'm able to get a match on line 3 using the following regex:

```
\s+(?|(DNS):([\w\.\d]+),|(IP Address):([\d\.]+))
```

But then, when I add a positive lookbehind, as below, I no longer get a full match.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
(?<=X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:\s)\s+(?|(DNS):([\w\.\d]+),|(IP Address):([\d\.]+))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are extracting you may simplify your pattern greatly to `(DNS|IP Address):([\w.]+)`, where the IP address is matched with `[\w.]+` same as DNS, as `\w` also matches digits. Then, to define a custom boundary, you may use a `\G` based pattern like

```
(?:\G(?!\A),\s*|X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:\s+)(DNS|IP Address):([\w.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1B0Kq/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A),\s*|X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:\s+)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A),\s*` - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) and then a comma and 0+ whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:\s+`  - `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:` substring and then 1+ whitespaces
- `(DNS|IP Address)` - Group 1: `DNS` or `IP Address`
- `:` - a colon
- `([\w.]+)` - Group 2: one or more word (letters, digits or `_`) or dot chars.

Comment: That's impressive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When we add a positive lookbehind only the first entry in the next line will match because for the rest of the IP addresses or DNS names, the positive lookbehind is not really just before them. The text `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:` is before only the first IP address or DNS name.

This is the lookbehind pattern **(Pattern 1)**:

```
(?<=X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:)\s+(DNS:([\w\.\d]+),|IP Address:([\d\.]+))
```

And this is the IP address or DNS names pattern **(Pattern 2)**:

```
\s+(DNS:([\w\.\d]+),|IP Address:([\d\.]+))
```

Hence, you will have to do this, I think:

1. First check if the text matches Pattern 1. This will ensure that you have picked up a line or entry that you need.
2. Next, apply the Pattern 2 and pick the values.

I tested it on Java and found it working. Since you mentioned PHP in the title, I thought the code may not be of use to you. Hence, not posting.